# Polling Unix Commands Top

Tags: unix

How might I display an up to date display of `top` inside of Mathematica?

`top` is unique in that it updates itself every couple of seconds.

The following works for basic commands like `ls` but not `top` for some reason.

```
Import["!LD_LIBRARY_PATH= top", "Text"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the proper flags with [`top`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html). For example `-b` is for batch mode which is more appropriate for sending the output to another program. We are getting 1 frame (`-n 1`) before ending.

You can use something like the following:

```
Dynamic[RunProcess[{"top","-b", "-n 1"}, "StandardOutput"],
        UpdateInterval->2, TrackedSymbols:>{}]
```

I added [`TrackedSymbols :> {}`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) to lock the refreshes to the [`UpdateInterval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpdateInterval.html).

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
process = StartProcess[$SystemShell];
WriteLine[process, "top"];
Dynamic[ReadString[process, "Processes: "], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

The reason you can't use `Import` is probably because the `top` process doesn't terminate. It's the same thing if you try to use `ReadString` without a second argument, it won't return anything because it will be waiting for the process to terminate first.

Since `top` will continuously fill the buffer we have to detect somehow when one table ends and a new begins. A new table begins with the word "Processes", so I used that.

Comment: are you on mac or linux?

Comment: @Liam Mac, if it doesn't work try `ReadString[process, EndOfBuffer]` and see if that returns something.

Comment: It freezes ubuntu so far for me.  I will add a bounty in 2 days.

Comment: @Liam If you run `ReadString[process, EndOfBuffer]` not inside `Dynamic`, but on its own, it freezes?

Comment: It freezes on and off.  It isn't entirely unusable.  If I run what you posted without or without `ReadString[process, EndOfBuffer]` it freezes on and off.

Comment: @Liam Ah, that I can understand. I noticed on my computer too that it slows down the interface, not enough to "freeze" but still. My focus here was on getting the information into *Mathematica*, and this seems to have been achieved. Now, displaying such a large block of text and updating it regularly without having a performance hit is another problem that I didn't look into.