# How to know the real-time memory consumption value of a specified process

Tags: memory, interoperability, windows

I'm on *Windows 10*, when I run my c++ program, the task manager will show the real-time memory consumption value of the `.exe` process. I want to plot a conditional curve for this value to simulate the page **Performace in task manager**:

[image]

But how can I use to Mathematica to get this value?

Comment: Related: [Polling Unix Command Top](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129708/polling-unix-commands-top). (Reading in and dispaying task manager statistics in Unix systems.)

Comment: @C.E. Thanks, and this post just care a specify process.